# Problem with Texture Opacity

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a complete beginner and I'm having some problems with my textures.

If you look at the image below, you can see that the texture appears to be transparent.

[image: model with bad textures]

What can I do to make it look like the texture in the original image?

**[Blend File](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10412411/Hase.blend.html)**

Comment: Hi, can you upload a .blend file please? It's hard to tell whats going on with the screenshot you provided as it doesn't even show the textures panel.

Comment: Hello! Here is the File: http://www.file-upload.net/download-10412411/Hase.blend.html , Thank you!

Comment: I need the texture also. Use "File->External Data->Pack Into .blend" to pack the texture into your .blend file and then re-upload. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thx! http://www.file-upload.net/download-10412447/Hase.blend.html
Now i even know how that works :D thx

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4hbJ3K2.png Thats the most actual result, without "calculate" set, but it still wont look 80% like that texture

Comment: I think that part is just the shading. You could try checking shadeless in the materials tab, but that gets rid of all shading. Make sure to accept A Radish's answer. It can be really annoying when you answer a question and the person asking it says it works but doesn't accept it.

Comment: You're spreading malware 'ADWARE/MultiPlug.Gen4' use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or http://pasteall.org/blend/.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a transparency problem, which I'm not sure that it is, then all you have to do is uc-check the box that says *Transparency* under the materials tab.

However! the *real* problem lies within your Fresnel shading, where you have the ramp pushed aaaalll the way over to the right. you want some breathing space between the two pushey-guys or the reflective effects are super dramatic. You might also want to change Fresnel to lambert. Fresnel has effects go further without dissipation so I think that's your problem.

Comment: That's the diffuse shading, it's what makes the black shading come so quickly. I don't think it affects the texture. I could be wrong though. I use cycles more than BI.

Comment: oops, I thought that was his specs...

Comment: he has the Ramp checked,and set the defuse to fresnel  so this could be the reason

Comment: I still think that's what it is. the way he has it is... unnatural. i'll see if I can't fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just set the deffuse to the default values :

[image]

here is what seems the problem uncheck this option

[image]

Comment: not-way-ahead of you... I just put Fresnel in. :( sorry. should I take it out?

Comment: @ARadish No this is more of a comment than an answer :)

Comment: Hello! Thank you, i tried that now, but nearly no option has an effect on that - I Use "general" instead of UV Map, is that a problem?

Comment: Simon! it's under the materials. not the textures. you can see it in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes! http://i.imgur.com/Om8kppr.png that didn't work, though. -.- i tried nearly every option, im not in that good mood to texturing in mostly Modeling Programs, dunno why -.- :D

Comment: i guess it just hates me (Everything belonging to texturing)

Comment: I never really get it

Comment: @SimonDülpers does the edit work for you ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4hbJ3K2.png

Comment: Do you know some option / have an idea to make the original texture even more Shiny & Contrastful? i dont really know what im doing there, so if changing the Lamp settings / Change render options 7 Change Materiel or Texture options make it become like the original picture, pls let me know :)

Comment: Yes, it dit, now its not milky anymore

Comment: @SimonDülpers in the material under shading set emit to >0 value (0.2)

Comment: Thx, but i did not find that :( http://i.imgur.com/xkRj1Rg.png

Comment: @SimonDülpers here it is [the image](http://imgur.com/mVNDpHl)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6g2rb2

Comment: Thy, but it makes no change!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6g2rb2

Comment: @SimonDülpers you have checked 'shadeless' where you should change the value next to it 'emit' , and a side advice 'start using cycles it's way better and simpler'

Comment: Yess! Finally :o

Comment: i set up "shadeless" to the wrong material -.- :O :D thx!!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6g2tuc Although, it looks a bit annoying now :D But big thx! i think because of that big trial and error and your help now, i get through that texture stuff soon, i think :D

Comment: @SimonDülpers just remember to try the Cycles render engine it is much simpler ( use nodes editor for material and texture)

Comment: What is it? :o Where do i find it ? :D Sorry i came from a map editor (Valve hammer Editor), but thats 14 Years back, now :O

Comment: @SimonDülpers here is a [video](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/09/16/introduction-blender-cycles-render-engine/) and [another one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTwXG3K4l2g) , and you should find more just in google